# If I let a string reference escape, will this prevent the containing object to be garbage-collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Suppose I have an object containing a string as follows:

```
class SomeObject  {
   private final String s;
   private final int i;

   SomeObject(String s, int i) {
      this.s = s;
      this.i = i;
   }

   String getString() {
      return s;
   }
}
```

So if I just use the reference without `SomeObject`, for example I use to build another object and I don't need `i` and any other possible fields, will it be garbage-collected?

Edit: I am sorry for not being clear. The thing is let's say I have a SomeObject instance named someObject and if I let the s reference escape with the getString() method, i.e. someObject.getString() and use the returning reference to build some other object, e.g. not a SomeObject instance, will the someObject be available to be garbage-collected?

Comment: What reference do you use? Reference to what?

Comment: Will WHAT be garbage-collected?

Comment: I edited the question a bit, I hope that's better. FYI, I am not native

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're referring to `s`? Yes, instances of `SomeObject` will be free for garbage collection. The `String` holds no reference to the `SomeObject` from which it originated.

Comment: So as a general rule, if a field does not hold a reference to the containing object, the containing object can be garbage collected right?

Comment: @user1364534: Yes, and even more in general, if there is no reference to something, it can be garbage-collected.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was confused because inner classes is a cause of memory leak as they hold reference to the outer class thus preventing them to be garbage-collected. And I thought to myself if that would be the case for the question I asked.

Btw do you know if a static inner class would prevent any outer class to be garbage collected. For example let's say the class A contains a definition of a static inner class B. Will the instantiation of a B object prevent all instance of A to be garbage collected?

Comment: @user1364534 No, a static inner class does not have an automatic reference to any instance of the outer class, and therefore does not prevent them from being garbage collected. That's the whole point of the static inner class.

Answer (score 2):

`getString()` will return `s`, but it will not "delete" it from the current `SomeObject`. If a value `x` is assigned to `s`

```
s = x;
```

`x` will only be garbage collected if you assign a new value `y` to `s`

```
s = y;
```

and there is no reference to `x` left.

Answer (score 2):

Let me ask you this.

```
final class Foo {
  String value = "initial";
}
```

Say you execute code as follows...

```
final Foo foo = new Foo();
final String val = foo.value;
foo.value = "replaced";
```

Now, do you think `val` will now equal `"replaced"`? Hopefully not, as it won't; it appears you have some misunderstanding of what a reference is. With `val = foo.value`, you are copying the value of the field `foo.value` into `val`; the value is the reference to the string that is `"initial"`. It is *not* a reference to the field `foo.value`. Holding on to the reference to `"initial"` does not prevent `foo` from being garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks, I know what a reference is. I just wanted to know if the relation between the objects and their fields go deeper than what I knew. Although it is natural that they don't, but using a very high level language like Java, I just couldn't be sure.